# WordPress: Not displaying changes of updated pages

Tags: wordpress, updating

I have update a page in my wordpress site using web admin back end, but what I see is that even if I update a page, it does not get updated online. Moreover, some of the content of the page which I see online /live are not actually texted in the area where we put the content.

On the right side navigator, in the page attribute area Parent has been set to No Parent, template --> Home Page.

Can you please let me know what could be the possible reason why the live content of the page is different from what I can see in the actual text area through web admin panel?

Also updating a page does not reflects on the page as well for that particular page.

Comment: send me your details if possible wp-admin

Comment: @ Loic The Aztec thank you for your suggestion but we cant resolve issue without checking the url or admin panel

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are editing the right page. Click in the frontend adminbar on edit instead of navigating in the backend through the pages list.

Secondly it can be any caching related issue. Check out if there are any plugins or settings for this.

Areas that are on the page but not editable via the content can be widgets or any kind of theme builder stuff. Check in the backend design->widgets.

The page hierarchy (parent: no parent) can be differ from the actually website navigation. Check out design->menus. It is possible to build other hierarchies in the menus.